# Entity Designer for .edmx file doesn't work in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, edmx, entity-model

I have a .edmx file and I can't open it with the designer. It just opens as plain XML file. When I try to "run custom tool" on it, then it says that:

*The custom tool 'EntityModelCodeGenerator' failed. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.VSXmlDesignerBase, Version=10.0.0.0, ...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

And indeed, I don't have this file on my system. I've tried copying it to my machine, but then I get:

*An error occurred loading the Entity Data Model Tools Package.*

I have VS2010 SP1 Professional installed.

I've tried repairing and reinstalling VS and SP1, and installing some entity packages/patches (I don't remember the exact names of them), but that didn't help. What else can I try?

Comment: That's surely a strange behaviour. EDMX support is integrated in Vs2010, the only thing that comes to my mind is that something got corrupted. Try a clean install, I know it takes a lot of time but it's surely the best shot.

Comment: Did you have installed any previous CTP for new version of Entity framework?

Comment: What is CTP? Is it some sort of patch?

Comment: CTP stands for Community Technology Preview. It's generally an incomplete preview of a new technology in progress. These usually come out before beta and are a way to gather feedback from the community during the development of a product. (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/15/understanding-beta.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my installation package didn't have the L2E tools.

Comment: Could you give the URL for specifically "Link to Entities Tools"?